# Create and deploy a plugin for Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: plugins, tfs-2015, extensibility

I want to create automation for Team foundation Server 2015.

I want my logic to happen every time tfs user changes the state of a WIT.

How do i create and deploy it?

Comment: This is what i was searching for: https://socialtfs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20create%20and%20debug%20a%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%20server-side%20plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your logic in a server side TFS plugin; basically it's a class that implements ISubscriber.

See [TFS 2013 event handling on work item change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002496/tfs-2013-event-handling-on-work-item-change)