# Which of my two approach is right to update SQL table from TFS workitem collection object

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, tfs, tfs-workitem

I had developed one small application which will fetch data from TFS project workitemcollection object and store it into SQL table.

Now I want to update database regularly. What I have done is, I have created as service which will create new tfs project workitemcollection object and update database based upon two checks i.e. if defect id is already present in table it will update the SQL row with new values and if not it will insert the new values.

**ISSUE**: In one scenario the defect from one tfs project has been moved to another tfs project but SQL still contains that id in old project.

**Ways I can think of**: another check from opposite direction to verify if defectId is not present in collection then delete it.
OR,
Every time service run delete the old table and fill the complete table with new and updated data.

What will be the best option or if there is third one?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating a server side plugin for TFS to listen to the work item change event. Once the event triggered, create/update/delete the record in your SQL table.

If you use TFS 2013 and previous versions, check [TFS 2013 event handling on work item change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002496/tfs-2013-event-handling-on-work-item-change) to create the server plugin.

If you use TFS 2015 and later versions, including the solution above in TFS 2013, you can also use [Web Hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/webhooks) to send a JSON representation of an [event](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/events) to any service.